# Copying table in ArcGIS Desktop and keeping same feature ID (objectID)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase, copy, objectid

What geoprocessing tool  can I use to copy a table from an ArcSDE Geodatabase to a Personal Geodatabase, keeping the feature ID (objectID)?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411583/copying-object-id-from-an-online-layer-to-offline-one-using-feature-class-to-fea/411627#411627

Answer (score 5):

There is no Geoprocessing tool to do this and I think that there is no case for one to be developed because, as [commented by @blah238](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72495/copying-table-in-arcgis-desktop-and-keeping-same-feature-id-objectid/72521#comment98941_72495):

> You should not rely on the consistency of ObjectIDs for any purpose.
>   Instead, you should have a persistent and unique ID in a separate
>   column. In a pinch you could just calculate a new field based on the
>   current ObjectID and use that going forward.

Answer (score 4):

Just as with most GIS professionals, I do NOT condone the use of ObjectID as a unique ID. Unfortunately, I have been to numerous facilities where they STILL do this. In turn I have had to come up with a work around myself.

To answer your direct question, if you COPY the feature class whether it be to an "_1" and then renamed or to another geodatabase, or in SDE, the system will preserve the existing ObjectID field but it will also create a NEW ObjectID_1 field that will become the unique identifier. This does make for slightly messy table structure, but it will give you the opportunity to create a new unique ID and/or reference the old ObjectIDs if required.

If you do this through an Import or a Data Load, the old ObjectID will NOT be brought over. Similar to blah238's suggestion, I set up a trigger on the a tables in SQL to automatically calculate the UniqueID equal to the ObjectID when a feature is created. This way, if my data becomes corrupt, needs to be moved, etc, I still have that UniqueID to fall back on.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://community.esri.com/thread/81403#comment-346603) and am copying here just in case. This is particularly helpful if you want to transfer attachment relation class' feature class(es) because they operate over OBJECTIDs.

Basically it suggests using `FeatureSet` for this purpose. Unlike `Copy_management` which expects a full dataset as input and creates an exact copy, this can process map layers and honours the selection.

```
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fs.load("a layer from TOC or any feature class")
fs.save(output_location)
```

If you want to copy a table, the first line can be modified as:

```
fs = arcpy.RecordSet()
```

Comment: I tried to work with this but it is returning an empty feature class instead of copying the features.

Comment: Does `fs.JSON` return anything? Did you try to load another sde dataset and maybe to use an empty personal geodatabase (mdb) to test? I just tested the procedure and it works fine.