# ArcMap ObjectID seems to be getting changed, any ideas what might be doing it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, query

I am working with ArcMap10.0 and MDB's, often creating Definition Queries based off my ObjectID with the understanding that this unique identifier should not change over time.  ie. if I create features 1,2,3,4 and then delete #2 I should still have features 1,3,4 with 3 & 4 not renumbering themselves to fill in the gap, correct?  If, after deleting feature 2, I then add feature 5 it will not 'replace' feature 2 but will be 5, and 2 will never be used again.

Is this a correct understanding of how an ObjectID in a feature class works?

My issue is that my Definition Queries are often not working when I revisit an old MXD,and when i check the OID's being DQ'd off I find they are different from the ones in the FC's attribute table.

I suspect the only way this could happen would be if the FC was copied into a new FC, then the features would renumber, but otherwise the numbers should not change, correct?

I want to still use OID's to DQ as it's the easiest thing to use for my purposes, but if I can't be sure that a feature with OID #1 will not stay #1, this won't work.

Comment: Any number of operations, from cleanup to geoprocessing, can alter the OID field. It's a system tracked and modified field you have no control over. If you want a persistent, unique ID, you have to create one yourself. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000z000000 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72495/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133161/ may provide more info.

Comment: Attribute Assistant GenerateID values are probably a better approach.  Everything you said was generally true, but the FC can never move to a publication location or another server.  I duplicate the OID value from my master edit location into a custom field to expose it in the publication server for tracking.  When server migration happens I have to resynchronize the values by exporting the old FIDs from my field and the new ObjectIDs and update them in every database or layer that relied on those values.  I use Feature Linked annotation, so I need those ObjectIDs saved for resynchronization.